# How to change the URL from the printing page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the URL that gets printed on the bottom of the page when using `window.print();`

like this : [image]

to a simple text like "powered by". I have found some solutions to remove the Url using css ,  so is there any way for changing it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your ability to customize the header/footer is pretty minimal, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't show custom text, you can change the url shown by calling

```
history.pushState({}, "", "URLtoShow");
window.print()
history.back()
```

Note that the url must be on the same domain as the page being printed. You can try to show text by calling

```
history.pushState({}, "", "#  "+messagetoshow);
window.print()
history.back()
```

but that might not work.